# Wordpress Permalink settings not working with apache on ubuntu 16.04 - getting site not found error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I know this question has been asked so many times. However, I had to post this since I have followed all of the posts and still getting this error.

I want to change my permalink settings with post name like http://www.example.com/sample-post. when I change that in the wordpress admin (settings/permalink) and save changes, I get page not found for any of my pages.

[image]

I see that wordpress has access to .htaccess file on the main folder since i removed it once and it got created when I restart my permalink settings in wordpress admin. (settings/permalink)

below is my etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```html
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

 
Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

 
Include ports.conf

 
<Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Satisfy all
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory /var/www/html/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>

 
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
 
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
 
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Thanks so much for reading this long post and helping a friend! And, please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Including an explanation of _why_ this fix works would improve this answer.